# Is there a way to user pairs for Rxjs5?

Tags: rxjs5

Can not find Rx.Observable.pairs in Rxjs5,
what I need just convert an object into Observable and inspect the change for each property.
any ideas?

```
 var a = { aa: "aa", bb: "bb" };
   function pairs(obj) {
    // List of object's key-value pairs
    var keyValuePairs = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({ key, value: obj[key] }));
    // Convert to an Observable and return
    return Rx.Observable.from(keyValuePairs);
    }

  var xxx = pairs(a);
xxx.subscribe(x => {
    console.log(x);
})

a.aa = "mm";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this from scratch:

```
function pairs(obj) {
    // List of object's key-value pairs
    var keyValuePairs = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({ key, value: obj[key]}));

    // Convert to an Observable and return
    return Rx.Observable.from(keyValuePairs);
}
```

Comment: I add the sample code, please help me on why when the properties change, I didn't get any log:Object {key: "aa", value: "aa"}
 Object {key: "bb", value: "bb"}

Comment: The code that I provided will not emit an event when properties change. Rather, it looks at the items *current* properties and creates an Observable based on those: this is how `Rx.Observable.pairs` in v4 worked.

Comment: you are right. pairs maybe not what I want. I want to have an Observable to observer any changes on an Object. could you please give me any instructions?

Comment: Any luck with this ? ive been looking for this functionality too